# JavaScript Number.MAX_VALUE

Tags: javascript

I'm currently playing around with large numbers in JavaScript and stumbled across something that I don't quite understand:

From the [Mozilla JavaScript Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_VALUE) I found the following statement:

> The MAX_VALUE property has a value of approximately 1.79E+308. Values
>   larger than MAX_VALUE are represented as "Infinity".

Just for fun I hacked some lines in my Google Chrome console to see what would happen if I used a larger number than Number.MAX_VALUE and I was surprised by the result:

```
Number.MAX_VALUE + 1 === Infinity
```

returns **false**.

```
Number.MAX_VALUE+Math.pow(10,291) === Infinity
```

returns **false**.

```
Number.MAX_VALUE+Math.pow(10,292) === Infinity
```

returns **true**.

Just by definition I would already expect the first example to return true. Why is that not the case? What am I missing?